# php array of object to array to object values

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have an array like this:

```
[
        {
            "date": "2019-05-10"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-05-20"
        },
    ]
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
['2019-05-10','2019-05-20']
```

what is the best way to do it in php?

Comment: Are those StdClass inside the first array ?

Comment: Create another array and run a foreach inside the first one transferring the values to the second array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$res = array_reduce($myArray, function($a, $b) {
  $a[] = $b->date;
  return $a;
}, []);
```